# Error while getting compile chudnovsky.c with GMP library

Tags: c

I have been download c source of chudnovsky to compute pi number in million digits at [this site](https://beej.us/blog/data/pi-chudnovsky-gmp/#comment-2455412702). and when I start to compile it, the error was showed like this [image]. please tell me about the error. I wanna this program work.

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images, insert them in your question

Comment: it was hard to explain, I don't understand about the error code :(

Comment: To copy text from console window, select the text in console window using the mouse, then click the right mouse button. Next, you will be able to paste the code in this window (click the "edit" button to edit your question). It will also be helpful if you post the source code which you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

from the list of error messages:

It seems the `gmp` library is not located at: c:\users\alin_c~1\appdata\local\gmp\  (assuming that the functions: `mpf_inits()`, etc are part of the `gmp` library)